# Template not found but there

Tags: node.js, express, dust.js

I have an `index.html` file that I'm trying to render using dustjs-linkedin but get the error:

```
500 Error: Template Not Found: C:\Users\Gilbert\WebstormProjects\NodeOfGames\views\index.html
```

The file `index.html` is definitely there. I'm using `app.engine('html', require('dustjs-linkedin').render);` to render .html files with dust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dust.render looks in dust.cache for the named template, which in your case is named

```
C:\Users\Gilbert\WebstormProjects\NodeOfGames\views\index.html
```

dust.render only renders compiled templates - which are automatically put in dust.cache upon load.

I don't think the template is in there. if it is, it probably isn't named with the above name.

what you may want is dust.renderSource instead. even so, you need to pass in a context and a callback - I'm not sure how that works in express.